# Radio button is checked jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of radio buttons inside a form which is in the body of a bootstrap 4 modal. I'm trying to see which one is checked, which should be a very simple thing to do but I'm struggling with it today and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

here is the HTML.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivitySedentary" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.2">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivitySedentary">Sedentary (little or no exercise)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityLight" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.375">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityLight">Light Activity (light exercise 1-3 days per week)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
   <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityMod" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.55">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityMod">Moderately Activity (moderate exercise 3-5 days per week)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityHeavy" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.725">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityHeavy">Very Active (hard exercise 5+ days per week)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityEx" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.9">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityEx">Extremely Active (very hard exercise 6+ days per week)</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  if ($("input[name='customRadioInline3']").is(':checked')) {
    alert("Checked")
  } 
}
```

And:

```
if ($("input[name='customRadioInline3']").is(':checked')) {
  alert("Checked")
}
```

the only thing that works is if I put this inside a button click (but I can't do that because I have to check the value before the submit button is executed).

Comment: None of your radio is checked. So no alert.

Comment: yeah, I'm clicking the radio buttons on the html browser.

Comment: You are using too much jquery: `if (elem = document.querySelector("input[name=customRadioInline3]:checked")) alert(elem.value + ' is checked')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the checked radio button on button click like the following way:

```js
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
  if($("input[name=customRadioInline3]:checked").length > 0){
    alert("Checked");
  }
  else{
    alert("Not checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivitySedentary" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.2" >
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivitySedentary">Sedentary (little or no exercise)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityLight" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.375">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityLight">Light Activity (light exercise 1-3 days per week)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityMod" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.55">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityMod">Moderately Activity (moderate exercise 3-5 days per week)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityHeavy" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.725">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityHeavy">Very Active (hard exercise 5+ days per week)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <input type="radio" id="tdeeActivityEx" name="customRadioInline3" class="custom-control-input" value="1.9">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="tdeeActivityEx">Extremely Active (very hard exercise 6+ days per week)</label>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click"/>
```

Comment: so i need to add the attribute "checked" if that button was clicked on

Comment: When do you want to  check the radio button status?

Comment: Ideally before a button click, but I suppose it could be after

Comment: Is that radio button or some other button like submit?

Comment: no. just a regular bootstrap button with a type of button.

Comment: No need. With your code and putting it inside a btn click event I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Let me see... first you select every input element named "customRadioInline3" and then you check each of them if they are checked... but they are radio-buttons so only one can be selected at a time... but you keep checking all the other elements even if the first element was the one that was selected....  Doesn't jquery support *:checked* like in `"input[name=customRadioInline3]:checked"` ?

Comment: @some, you are right. I have updated the answer...thanks for helping me to improve the answer.

Comment: @J.G.Sable, please notice the updated answer which is more elegant...thanks.

Comment: And there is no need to quote the name inside the query either: `[name=customRadioInline3]` is valid too and you don't need to remember if the string was quoted with single or double quotes or back-ticks.

Comment: Better! (now you only need to dump the jquery dependency too... )

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but `$("input[name='customRadioInline3']")` will return all the inputs in an array so you have to iterate them.

```
var radios=$("input[name='customRadioInline3']");
for(var i =0; i < radios.length; i++ ) {
    if(radios[i].checked) {
        alert("Checked");
    } 
}
```

In case you only want the checked one:

`$("input[name='customRadioInline3']:checked")`

use val() to get the value:

`$("input[name='customRadioInline3']:checked").val()`

Comment: It says like this in the question: "I'm trying to see which one ***is checked***", so I'm positive that the op would like  to get the selected element, if there is one. Welcome to Stack Overflow and what looks like it was your first post.